# TableView reorder permanently in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a simple tableView running in my app with a reorder tableViewCell function.when I try to reorder the cell.reordering works.but when I close the app and reopen it cell order come back to normal.I wondering how to save the new order cell in swift.my simple code as follows nothing special its a simple tableview....

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


  var tableData: [String] = ["Argentina", "Brazil", "Australia","Austria", "Chile", "Denmark","Colombia", "Denmark", "Czech Republic","Egypt", "Ireland", "Germany","Hong Kong", "Netherlands", "Mexico","Poland", "Switzerland", "Panama","United Arab Emirates", "Belgium", "Armenia"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    self.tableView.reloadData()

  }

  // Toggle editing mode on/off
  @IBAction func reorderItems(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(tableView.editing == true) {
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }

  }

  // Set editing mode to show 3 bars on right hand side
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var itemToMove = tableData[sourceIndexPath.row] 
    tableData.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    tableData.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

    self.tableView.reloadData()

  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell   {

    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
  }
}
```

thanks...

Comment: Where are you getting the data for the table?

Comment: Did you update your `dataSource`? Reordering the rows is just a UI update. You need to make sure your dataSource reflects that reorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve a custom order you need to save the array to user defaults.
Although `NSUserDefaults` is not recommended for large data sets, let's use it in this sample code.

**AppDelegate**

- In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add 3 lines to register default values.

  ```
  let countries = ["Argentina", "Brazil", "Australia","Austria", "Chile", "Denmark","Colombia", "Denmark", "Czech Republic","Egypt", "Ireland", "Germany","Hong Kong", "Netherlands", "Mexico","Poland", "Switzerland", "Panama","United Arab Emirates", "Belgium", "Armenia"]
  let defaultValues = ["countries" : countries]
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaultValues)
  ```

**ViewController**

- Declare `tableData` as empty array.

  ```
  var tableData = [String]()
  ```
- In `viewWillAppear` add

  ```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  tableData = defaults.objectForKey("countries") as! [String]
  tableView.reloadData()
  ```
- Replace method `reorderItems` with

  ```
  @IBAction func reorderItems(sender: AnyObject) {

    if tableView.editing == true {
       tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
       let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
       defaults.setObject(tableData , forKey: "countries")
    } else {
       tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: i tried your suggestion to  reorder function in  AppDeleage method  in applicationWillEnterForeground. but no luck so far . can you elaborate how to do it and  i upload my code please take a look .thanks